# How to change a div class dynamically in a loop

Tags: css, jsp, jstl

I am using Spring4 and JSTL.
The image shown below consist of elements that are dynamically created in a JSP page.

[image]

code in jsp page

```
<c:forEach var="themes" items="${Itemlist}">
    <div  class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6"> 
            <!-- small box -->


            <div id="style" class="small-box bg-green" >


                   <!--div contents  --> 


           </div>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I need to change the div with id="style" class dynamically

small-box bg-red

small-box bg-blue

small-box bg-green

small-box bg-yellow ,all can change the box colour.How can i apply that dynamically.

Please help.

Comment: This shouldn't really be tagged with CSS as it's more of a question on how to reference a certain style than how to perform a given style; could lead a few people here with CSS knowledge who more than likely don't know anything about JSP

Comment: use if statement, and put logic in it. On what condition you want to change

Comment: @Jackhardcastle,@Sarz thanks for the reply.i have got the output as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be simply solved by using `<c:if>` and `varStatus` .

```
<c:forEach var="themes" items="${Itemlist}" varStatus="status">
  <div  class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6"> 

  <c:set var="color" value="green"/>      

  <c:if test="${status.index == 1}">
      <c:set var="color" value="red"/> 
  </c:if>
  ...
    <div id="style" class="small-box ${color}" ></div>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i got Finally. @ko2ic

[image]